# How to prevent catch up of a DAG?

Tags: airflow

I have the following DAG:

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 07, 19, 11,0,0),
    'email': ['me@me.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    'catchup' : False,
    'depends_on_past' : False,
}


with DAG('some_dag', schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=30), max_active_runs=1, default_args=default_args) as dag:
```

This dag runs every 30 minutes. It rewrite data in the table (delete all and write). So if Airflow was down for 2 days there is no point in running all the missing dag runs during that time.

However the above definition does not work. After 2 days that airflow was down it still try to run all the missing tasks.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 10):

OK. I solved it.
Apparently there is no meaning for `'catchup' : False` on the `default_args` . It does nothing.
I changed the code to

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 07, 19, 11,0,0),
    'email': ['me@me.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=2),
    'depends_on_past' : False,
}


with DAG('some_dag', catchup=False, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=30), max_active_runs=1, default_args=default_args) as dag:
```

now it works.

Answer (score 8):

according to the docs: https://airflow.apache.org/scheduler.html#backfill-and-catchup

- Adding `dag.catchup = False` to the DAG args.
- Adding `catchup_by_default = False` to the `airflow.cfg`

Depends on your use case, a good practice could be set `catchup_by_default = False` and then only use `dag.catchup = True` if a given DAG requires the catchup.